# Not able to delete details of executed bach job from SFDC

Tags: classic

I have executed one batch class in sandbox but after that I want to delete the batch class execution details like ID and All.

Comment: What are you up to man?? :p

Comment: This question is short, and lacking in detail. Please take some time to read through the topics in the [help], and specifically [ask]. Where are you seeing these details? Why do you want to delete them? What research have you done so far, and what have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

All batch jobs that have completed execution are removed from the batch queue list **seven days after completion**.

There is a method by which you can delete jobs executed before today, but it will delete all jobs and not only a single entry.

```
Integer count = System.purgeOldAsyncJobs
   (Date.today());
System.debug('Deleted ' + 
   count + ' old jobs.');
```